# how to change a CesiumJS viewer's baselayer url

Tags: cesiumjs

i am using a CesiumJS instance to display a base map of the earth using a imageryProvider from source A.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', imageryProvider:providerA);
```

Now while using the Viewer I would like to be able to change this map to get images from providerB at a certain event.

I tried:

```
viewer.scene.imageryLayers.get(0).imageryProvider.url = providerB.url
```

However that does not seem to work and also feels quite like hack anyway.
I could not find anything in Cesium's documentation .
Is this at all possible without restarting / recreating the viewer instance? 
I know that there is a Cesium.BaseLayerPicker (https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/BaseLayerPicker.html) 
However I do not see what method this picker calls on "select" )

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BaseLayerPicker widget [calls this code](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/blob/de92ad61bfa764206faf6ffd904cea733d86bbca/Source/Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/BaseLayerPickerViewModel.js#L175-L221) when the user selects a new layer.

There's a lot of boilerplate widget management in that block of code, but for your sake, only a couple of the lines are critical.  First, the old existing active imagery layer is searched for, and removed:

```
    imageryLayers.remove(layer);
```

Then, a new imagery provider is constructed and added at index 0, the first position, which is the base imagery layer:

```
    imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(newProviders, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change the URL of the provider but you should also change appropriate parameters("layers" in case of WMS, "layer", "style", "format", "tileMatrixSetID " ... in case of WMTS) depending on the type of provider(WMS or WMTS).